# Why does this MySQL query work on my production server but not my local test server?

Tags: mysql

This is the query I am trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO Article (id, name, title, author, dateCreate, dateEdit, permissions, template, views, tags) VALUES ('', 'test_show', 'Test Show', '1', '2018-03-24 18:47:09', '2018-03-24 18:47:20', '', '', '', '')
```

When I run it on my production server, which is hosted on DreamHost, and I believe [is running MySQL version 5.6](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215099117-MySQL-overview), it works.

On my local testing machine, though, which is running `MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21`, when I run the same query I get this error:

`#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1`

The database is structured exactly the same on both servers. Column 'id' is set to auto increment.

I need to make my local test server behave the same way my production server does, so is there some setting difference between the versions of MySQL that I need to adjust? In any case, how do I make the query work on my local test server?

Comment: Different `sql_mode`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables

Comment: @Caramiriel, thank you for that information, but can you elaborate more on exactly what aspect of `sql_mode` would need to change in order to make my local test server accept the query? It seems there are multiple options, and it's not clear which exactly I should be adjusting and how.

Comment: Sure. `SELECT @@sql_mode;` shows you the current `sql_mode` being used. You can compare what the values are in production and local test. In order to change them, one of the options is to change the configuration file (such as `my.ini`/`my.cnf`). This controls how "strict" MySQL needs to be, resulting in less surprising results in ambiguous situations. In your example setting an empty text (string) value to a numeric value isn't allowed. More info, such as the various levels of strictness on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

since id is set to auto-increment, you don't need to add it in the query. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Article (name, title, author, dateCreate, dateEdit, permissions, template, views, tags) VALUES ('test_show', 'Test Show', '1', '2018-03-24 18:47:09', '2018-03-24 18:47:20', '', '', '', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. But, since the query works on my production server, I need to make the query work on my local test server without changing making changes to the query itself.

Comment: IMO this is the best and most clear way for auto-increment fields.

Comment: I don't disagree. I'm just forced to maintain the query as it's structured on the server, so unfortunately using this solution is not an option for me.